# Showing Labels When Evaluating TensorFlow-Slim

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, tf-slim

I am teaching myself TensorFlow and am currently experimenting with different models for image classification in the [`tensorflow/models/slim`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/) repo. Following the tutorial there, I have fine-tuned a pre-trained `inception_v2_resnet` model and am trying to [evaluate](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim#evaluating-performance-of-a-model) it. I was wondering if there would be any simple way to modify the [`eval_image_classifier.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/eval_image_classifier.py) script to print the labels of the images that it is classifying? This would help in adapting this script for use with a test set.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this post is a little bit old, but I'am playing with tensorflow in this period. Maybe someone checking this post will find an answer here.

You can print within the evaluation loop the eval_op which can handle other data rather than only names_to_updates.values(). 
Originally it would be written as that:

```
eval_op = list(names_to_updates.values())
```

But you can change it to that:

```
eval_op = tf.Print(list(names_to_updates.values()), [predictions], message="predictions:", summarize=100)
```

An example output:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [1/111]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] predictions:[11 3 3 9]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [2/111]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] predictions:[8 10 3 7]
```

The numbers in the array after "Predictions:" are the number of the labels outputted.

In the same way you can output for example mislabeled image filenames as written here ([How to get misclassified files in TF-Slim's eval_image_classifier.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065063/how-to-get-misclassified-files-in-tf-slims-eval-image-classifier-py/45270171#45270171))

Answer (score 1):

The [evaluate](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/evaluation.py#L210) function in slim is the one responsible for actually calling session.run on the images, so there's the place you want to modify.

Comment: In that case, I guess I'd have to rebuild tensorflow after my modifications.

Comment: were you able to do this task? I don't see an array of labels or so available under evaluate function.

Comment: @Ogail I haven't had the opportunity to finish this task.